# Misleading training data shuffle for stateful GRU in Tensorflow text_generation tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm looking into Tensorflow text_generation tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation) and wondering why they are shuffle training data although the stateful for GRU layer is set TRUE?

This contradicts the documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RNN):
*"Note on using statefulness in RNNs: You can set RNN layers to be 'stateful', which means that the states computed for the samples in one batch will be reused as initial states for the samples in the next batch. This assumes a one-to-one mapping between samples in different successive batches."*

Code snippets from tutorial:

```
dataset = dataset.shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True)
```

```
tf.keras.layers.GRU(rnn_units,
                        return_sequences=True,
                        stateful=True,
                        recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
```

Comment: You are right, when the stateful is set to True, there is no need to shuffle the data. Since the stateful RNN makes sense  when you use **sequential** and **nonoverlapping** input sequences.  And also while creating batches instead of sequence length we could chop the entire text into n equal length where n is batch size, to create one dataset of consecutive input sequences for each of the batches.

Comment: What did you replace the code with in the end?

Comment: I also noticed this.  I thought that maybe it was a typo because they later go on to use statefulness when predicting, which is a valid use of it.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is wrong. I follow the steps from the TensorFlow documentation, but when I set `stateful=False` I get much better results with shuffled data.